# Updating JSON object using values from the displayed table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a table displayed using JSON object as below -

[image]

There`s an update button which is supposed to update(on onclick) the 'Phone2' value of the object as per the user edits in the Textbox and display the updated object in the form of a label below the table. The code used for the table is as follows -

**HTML**  -

```
<table id="personDataTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone1</th>
        <th>Phone2</th>
    </tr>

</table>

<input type="button" value="Update"/>
```

**Javascript -**

```
$.ajax({
    url: ' ',
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify([
            {
            id: 1,
            Name: "Peter",
            Phone1: "9878987",
            Phone2:"21"},
        {
            id: 2,
            Name: "David",
            Phone1: "9092345",
            Phone2:"23"},
        {
            id: 3,
            Name: "Rahul",
            Phone1: "9092345",
            Phone2:"90"}    
        ]),
        delay: 3
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        drawTable(data);
    }
});

function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Name + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Phone1 + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td><input id="+rowData.id+" type=text value=" + rowData.Phone2 + "></td>"));
}
```

There`s no other button/event involved apart from the ones mentioned. How can this work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]... Are you receiving a JSON or sending one? I thought sending JSON you stringify and receiving JSON you parse?

Comment: @zer00ne Hey! I am sending it. POST.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index5</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var gridData;

            $("#InitGrid").click(function () {

                var text = '[' +
                    '{ "id":1, "Name":"Peter" , "Phone1":"9878987", "Phone2":"21" },' +
                    '{ "id":2, "Name":"David" , "Phone1":"9092345", "Phone2":"23" },' +
                    '{ "id":3, "Name":"Rahul" , "Phone1":"9092345", "Phone2":"90" } ]';

                gridData = JSON.parse(text);

                drawTable(gridData)
            });

            $("#PostToServer").click(function () {
                //THIS WILl need to come from user
                gridData[0].Phone2 = $("td #1").val();
                gridData[1].Phone2 = $("td #2").val();
                gridData[2].Phone2 = $("td #3").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/GetPhone2',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(gridData),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $("#personDataTable").empty();
                        drawTable(data);
                    },
                    error: function (data, status, error) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });

            function drawTable(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    drawRow(data[i]);
                }
            }

            function drawRow(rowData) {
                var row = $("<tr />")
                $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
                row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Name + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Phone1 + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td><input id=" + rowData.id + " type=text value=" + rowData.Phone2 + "></td>"));
            }
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="personDataTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone1</th>
            <th>Phone2</th>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <input type="button" value="InitializeGrid" id="InitGrid" />
    <input type="button" value="PostToServer" id="PostToServer" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here is your Controller:

```
public class Phone2DTO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone1 { get; set; }
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetPhone2(IList<Phone2DTO> dto)
    {
        foreach (Phone2DTO p in dto)
        {
            if (p.id == 1)
            {
                p.Phone2 = "222222";
            }
            if (p.id == 2)
            {
                p.Phone2 = "333333";
            }
            if (p.id == 3)
            {
                p.Phone2 = "444444";
            }
        }
        return Json(dto);
    }

    public ActionResult Index5()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You need to initialize first then Post to server.

Comment: Hey! Is there a way to do this clientside only so that I can send the modified object to a service call?